# What do question marks mean in crossword clues?

Tags: crosswords

In a crossword, some clues have a question mark at the end. Is there any way to tell what these question marks mean based on the puzzle? I.E. rhetorical, compound word, etc.?

Comment: There are several schools of crossword puzzles. Are these cryptic crosswords or not? British, US or other?

Comment: In the US crosswords I am familiar with, the question mark indicates that the answer will be a stretch, pun, or generally "questionable". I usually refer to it as a "smart-ass mark" in that context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's only one canonical example I can find of a crossword using question marks to mean anything special.

Many American crossword puzzles (for instance, the New York Times) rely on a convention that, if a clue ends in a question mark, it's a play on words.

> Mental Block?
>
> RUBIKSCUBE

It can also be used to indicate something only loosely related to the topic:

> Cause for a head slap?
>
> BONER

In essence, the clue shouldn't be taken too literally. The British use an exclamation mark for a similar purpose.

Comment: Yep, this.  The key distinction for these is that the most common reading of the term or phrase in the clue is never the one the answer is linked to.

Comment: It took me a while to remember the other (intended) meaning of "boner," and was really having some trouble figuring that one out.

Comment: @KSmarts On the other hand, if you interpret "head" and "slap" the right way, it could still make sense the first way...